# Java selenium can't login to ebay? "oops, that's not a match"

Tags: java, selenium

So my own google chrome browser lets me log into ebay no problem but when i create the script to login it's keep throwing me a error "oops, that's not a match" even though i tried changing from chrome drive to gecko drive but it's still giving me the error. this is my code

```
String  baseUrl = "https://www.ebay.com/";
      org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
      proxy.setSslProxy(read[0] + ":" + parsingInt);       
      DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
      desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
      ChromeDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver(desiredCapabilities);
      chrome.get(baseUrl);
      chrome.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&ru=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2F'] ")).click();
      chrome.findElement(By.id("userid")).sendKeys(readAcc[0]);
      chrome.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(readAcc[1]);
      chrome.findElement(By.id("sgnBt")).click();
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      chrome.quit();
```

Comment: "oops, that's not a match" is not a very descriptive error.  Does it open the browser?  Does it navigate to the ebay home page?  Does it enter a user id and password?  Is it clicking the button?  At what point does it report this particular error?  Print your user ID and password to the console and confirm that they are correct.  Since your password would only show as asterisks, you need to verify that the password is what you think it is.